# UICollectionView compositional layout with orthogonal scrolling and a different size for last cell

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

We’re attempting to use `UICollectionView` compositional layout to describe a section layout, but it’s giving us some trouble.

What we’d like to achieve:

- A total of 7 cells
- 3 cells stacked, each 30% height and 100% width, with orthogonal scrolling to see the next 3
- When the user reaches the last cell, it would be 100% height and 100% width of the container.

ASCII art and screenshots of the imperfect example are below.

Our starting point was Apple’s [example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views), specifically `OrthogonalScrollingViewController`, but what we’ve found is if we expand the widths there, the height settings seem to longer be respected.

The most basic version of a layout that we tried is this:

```swift
  func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
      (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
      
      // Small items at roughly 30% of the container height.
      let smallItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
          widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.3)
        )
      )

      // The large item should be 100% of the container width.
      let largeItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
          widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
        )
      )

      // We want 3 items to appear stacked with orthogonal scrolling.
      let smallItemGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
          widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
        ),
        subitem: smallItem,
        count: 3
      )
      
      let containerGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
          widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
          heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5)
        ),
        subitems: [smallItemGroup, largeItem]
      )
      
      let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: containerGroup)
      section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .paging
      
      return section
    }
    
    return layout
  }
```

We’ve tried many variations of nested groups and using the `.vertical` and `.horizontal` initializers, but each of them has the same result: The last cell is always the same size as all the others.

```
  //   +------------------------------+                  These would be off-screen
  //   | +-------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+  +-------------------------+
  //   | |            1            |  |  |            4            |  |                         |
  //   | +-------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+  |                         |
  //   | +-------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+  |                         |
  //   | |            2            |  |  |            5            |  |            7            |
  //   | +-------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+  |                         |
  //   | +-------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+  |                         |
  //   | |            3            |  |  |            6            |  |                         |
  //   | +-------------------------+  |  +-------------------------+  +-------------------------+
  //   |                              |
  //   |                              |
  //   |                              |
  //   |     rest of the screen       |
  //   |                              |
  //   |                              |
  //   |                              |
  //   |                              |
  //   +------------------------------+
```

[image: Page 1 with the first 3 cells]
[image: Page 2 with the second 3 cells]
[image: Page 3 with desired large cell]

The last cell in the third screenshot, (0,6), is the one we want 100% height of the section.

Is there a way to achieve this layout where the last cell is 100% of the section height?

Comment: I may have a solution for you, but... Will you have **exactly 7 cells**? Or, is that just an example number? And... are you specifically needing a collection view, or are you open to other options?

Answer (score 0):

Couple notes...

**First:** if you will only have **exactly 7 cells** - no more, no less - this layout would be very easy to do with stack views in a scroll view.

**Second:** I have only taken a cursory look at Compositional / Orthogonal layouts, so it's very possible there is a much better solution than what follows. But, it may be worth looking at.

**Third:** you have probably already figured some of this out, but I'll go step-by-step for clarity.

---

So, using Apple's [Implementing Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) sample code, focusing on `OrthogonalScrollingViewController` (we'll change number of Sections to 1 and number of items to 7).

Using the original `createLayout()` code, we get this (as you're aware):

[image]

**Step 1** - I think Apple did a very bad job with naming, so I'm changing:

- `leadingItem` to `singleItem`
- `trailingItem` to `doubleItem`
- `trailingGroup` to `doubleVerticalGroup`
- `containerGroup` to `repeatingGroup`

What this clarifies, to me, is that we've defined a vertical group of two items, and a horizontal group of two items (`subitems: [singleItem, doubleVerticalGroup]`), which will *repeat* (the result, of course, looks the same):

[image]

**Step 2** we can change the order easily, by swapping the order of the repeating group's `subitems: [doubleVerticalGroup, singleItem])`:

[image]

**Step 3** - I find it a bit confusing to have a *single item* and a *vertical group of items*, so I'll "embed" the single item in a vertical group all by itself:

```
// let's create a "singleVerticalGroup" - based on "doubleVerticalGroup"
let singleVerticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
    // width is percentage of "parent"
    // height is percentage of "parent"
    //  subitem is 1 singleItem (count: 1), arranged vertically
    // width of this group is what the singleItem width used to be
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.7),
                                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
    subitem: singleItem, count: 1)
```

and change our `repeatingGroup` items to:

```
subitems: [doubleVerticalGroup, singleVerticalGroup])
```

No difference in appearance (yet):

[image]

**Step 4** - Your layout wants "vertical / vertical / single" so let's change the `repeatingGroup` to:

```
subitems: [doubleVerticalGroup, doubleVerticalGroup, singleVerticalGroup])
```

And we're close to what we want:

[image]

Whoops! What happened to the "single" vertical group? Well, we had the the "double vertical group" element width set to 30% of its parent and the "single vertical group" element width set to 70% of its parent ... so now we have:

```
30%  30%  70%
```

Which, of course, doesn't fit into 100% ... so,

**Step 5** - let's set the element widths to 1/3

```
let fWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 / 3.0

let singleVerticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
    // width of this group is now 1/3
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(fWidth),
                                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
    subitem: singleItem, count: 1)
        
let doubleVerticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
    // width of this group is now 1/3
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(fWidth),
                                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
    subitem: singleItem, count: 2)
```

and we're getting much closer:

[image]

**Step 6** - your design wants **3** items stacked vertically, not **2**, so let's name it `tripleVerticalGroup` and change `count: 2` to `count: 3`:

```
let tripleVerticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
    //  subitem is 3 singleItems, arranged vertically
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(fWidth),
                                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
    subitem: singleItem, count: 3)
```

and our `repeatingGroup` items:

```
let repeatingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
    // width is percentage of "parent"
    // height is percentage of "parent"
    //  subitem is now 3 "groups" arranged horiztonally ...
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.85),
                                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.4)),
    subitems: [tripleVerticalGroup, tripleVerticalGroup, singleVerticalGroup])
```

and we get:

[image]

**Step 7** - the last thing we need to do is adjust the layout so each element in our `repeatingGroup` fills the width of the view.

We note that the `repeatingGroup` layout size used:

```
widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.85)
```

so let's change that to **3 times the width of the view** (its parent):

```
let repeatingGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(3.0),
                                       heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.4)),
    subitems: [tripleVerticalGroup, tripleVerticalGroup, singleVerticalGroup])
```

and the final output is (showing scrolling):

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

---

I created a GitHub repo here: https://github.com/DonMag/AppleModernCollectionViews with all of the above.